# Calling PHP from C program

Tags: php, c

I have a php function that I want to run from a C program. The file is '/path/auth.php' and the function is authenticate($user, $pwd). The function will echo either a 1 or 0 if a user has authenticated properly. I need to get this result back into the C program and then run other code based on the results. How should I go about it?

Comment: run how? via http request, or execute the php as a command line script?

Comment: I would just like to run it as a command line script.

Answer (score -1):

1. Add **PHP** to your environment variable **PATH**
2. The command to execute your script is `php path/auth.php`
3. Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4221665/4098311) to write your **[c](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/c)** code